# I have a problem with deploying flutter web to use in Line. (Scroll problem)

Tags: flutter, deployment, line, web-deployment

I have a problem with deploying flutter web to use in Line.

After I finished this task I deployed using firebase with the command "flutter build web --web-renderer html --release && cp -R build/web/* public && firebase deploy".

After deploying, the problem is that my app can't scroll. It's only open with line. If you open the same link in the browser, there will be no problem. Anyone have a solution? Can you recommend me?

Comment: you mean that suppose your app has singlechildscrollview and it doesn't work ?
is that you mean?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Would you please [edit] your question and add a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?